# localization nodejs (i18n)

Tags: node.js, localization

My code:

```
var i18n = require("i18n");

i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'ru'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    directory: __dirname + '/locales',
    cookiename: 'locale'
});

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(i18n.init);
})

app.get('/:locale', function (req, res) { 
    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale); 
    i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale); 
    res.redirect('/'); 
});
```

The problems are two:

1. In template does not work output through

   __("Name Key")
2. When the transfer is not directly through value, do not change text. There are all languages files

   res.render('index', {name: res.__('name') });
3. But do not switch languages​​

/* ----- */

The resulting code:

```
var i18n = require("i18n");

i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'ru'],
    defaultLocale: 'ru',
    directory: __dirname + '/locales'//,
    cookiename: 'locale'
});


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.__ = res.__ = function() {
        return i18n.__.apply(req, arguments);
    };
    next();
});

app.get('/i18n/:locale', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale);
    if (req.headers.referer) res.redirect(req.headers.referer);
    else res.redirect("/");
});
```

This works

Answer (score 4):

In your templates, assuming that you are using JADE you must embrace with `#{}`, like `#{__("Your key")}`

I didn't understand your second question, mind rephrasing?

Anyways, if you wanna use i18n from a controller, you must do: `res.render('index', {name: res.i18n.__('name') });`

---

When switching the language you must:
1- save user preference anywhere (session or cookies, for example)

```
app.get("/i18n/:locale", setLocale);

function setLocale(req, res, next){
    req.session.locale = req.params.locale;

    if(req.headers.referer) res.redirect(req.headers.referer);
    else res.redirect("/");
}
```

2- re-apply this change at every request (simply use a middleware):

```
var app = require("express")();

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.session.locale) //check if user has changed i18n settings
        req.i18n.setLocale(req.session.locale);
})

app.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    res.render('index', {name: res.i18n.__('name') });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: But do not switch languages​​, switching as follows: app.get('/:locale', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale);
    res.redirect('/');
});

Comment: check my edit! added some sample code, let me know if you understand that clear

Comment: continues to set the system language ... and not change its

Comment: this really helped me provide better language selection for my app.. just a couple notes (req.session) does not seem to be available until you enable the middleware using (express.cookieParser and express.cookieSession).. also, the language files were not being read until I FORCED the directory in i18n.configure (directory : __dirname + '/locales').. finally (res.redirect('back')) seems to be simpler than the conditional headers check. cheers!

Comment: Very helpful. This is how I ended up setting the locale when using cookies: `res.cookie('secret', req.params.locale, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from @renatoargh, I had to make some modifications, but here is the final block that seemed to get things working for me.

```
// configure i18n
i18n.configure({
    locales : [
        'en', 
        'zh'
    ],
    directory : __dirname + '/locales'
});

// configure app
app.configure(function () {
    // initialize session support
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.cookieSession({secret: uuid.v4()}));

    // initialize i18n
    app.use(i18n.init);

    // set locale (on every request), if session locale exists
    // otherwise use default browser setting
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        // check if user has changed i18n settings
        if (req.session.locale) {
            i18n.setLocale(req, req.session.locale);
        }

        next();
    });
});

// allow MANUAL locale selection
app.get("/i18n/:locale", function (req, res) {
    req.session.locale = req.params.locale;

    // go back to referrer OR root (/)
    res.redirect('back');
});
```

**NOTE** in the the configuration, I've set the `directory`. For some reason this was necessary, even though the docs state that its the default.

Also note that I'm using `secret: uuid.v4()`, but you can just hard-code this value for persistence across server restarts.